# Share video with facebook

Tags: php, facebook

I have an embed video(.flv file) in my webpage, i want to share this video to facebook.If i share this url to facebook it just show the url and it goes to my webpage, but i dont want this, i just want to play my video on facebook itself. Is it possibe?
help is highly appreciable.

## my embed code

```
<embed width="610" height="468" flashvars="file=616.flv" allowfullscreen="true" wmode="opaque" allowscriptaccess="always" src="player.swf" id="embedPlayer616">
```

Thanks,
VKS

Comment: refer the following link to accomplish this : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/#types under "Attaching Audio and Video Data" section

Comment: Did you want to upload a video or embed a video from other website (from your website)
Please refer Open Graph Protocol in facebook developer page also refer http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/flv/